# Caching XSD schema to reuse in several XML DOM parser tasks in Xerces

Tags: c++, xml, xerces, xerces-c

How can I cache an XSD schema (residing on disk) to be reused when parsing XMLs in Xerces (C++)?

I would like to load the XSD schema when starting the process, then, whenever I need to parse an XML, to validate it first using this loaded schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what I need [here](http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2010/01/25/multi-threaded-xml-parsing-validation-xerces-cxx/).

Comment: It is even possible to preparse the XSD schema files at build time and then include them inside the executable https://git.codesynthesis.com/cgit/xsd/xsd/tree/examples/cxx/tree/embedded